# WPS could not find printer in Ubuntu 18.04.1

Tags: 18.04, printing, wps-office

I had several attempts to get WPS to find my printer by installing WPS via the Ubuntu software application and it wouldn't work. Any Solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

I have just had the same issue on my newly installed Ubuntu 20.04. figured out that the application had no permission to access the printer. Went to the software center, opened WPS and checked the according checkbox in the permissions menu.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found to solve this issue was to download WPS directly from their own website and install it. After I've done that it found my printer automatically.